# C++ Functor overloading typedef to function pointer

Tags: c++, overloading, function-pointers, objective-c++, functor

I have this code:

Typedef to function pointer

```
typedef bool(*tMyFunc)(tSomeTypeDef);
```

The function pointer is used to declare a member var to point to a callback function in an Obj-C class

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    tSomeTypeDef _someValue;
    tMyFunc _callback;
}

- (void) registerNotificationWithCallback:(tMyFunc)callback;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void) registerNotificationWithCallback:(tMyFunc)callback {
    _callback = callback;
}

- (void) didSomething:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if (_callback)
        _callback(_someValue);
}
@end
```

In a C++ class, I want to pass a functor in place of a tMyFunc function pointer

```
class MyOtherClass {
    MyClass* m_instance;
public:
    bool operator ()(tSomeTypeDef val);
}

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass()
{
    //... init m_instance, then register callback as follows
    [m_instance registerNotificationWithCallback:*this];
}

bool MyOtherClass::operator ()(tSomeTypeDef val)
{
    return false;
}
```

It compile with the error

No viable conversion from 'MyOtherClass' to 'tMyFunc' (aka 'bool(*)(tSomeTypeDef)')

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Function pointers have more restricted semantics than function objects. You want to have your class be implemented in terms of function objects, not function pointers.

Comment: @DietmarKühl hmm, I don't want to use std::function to "typedef" a functor, I can't include stdlib in my build

Comment: I didn't say anything about `std::function` although it is a solution to the problem you have. However, yes, my point is that you need to use a type-erased function object if you don't want to be restricted to use function pointers. Cooking up a custom version of `std::function<void(T)>` isn't too hard, though.